# JBoss7 JPA EJB3 Multiple Data Sources dynamic configuration

Tags: jpa, datasource

I am using JBoss7 JPA and EJB3, and my application uses single EntityManager and single database at the moment.

The data source is configured in standalone.xml and and persistence.xml.

There is a new requirement to add support for multiple databases along with 1 common database (which is currently being used). What i need to do is, based on client's name, I need to choose the database where i would like to insert some data, and retrieve some. I am not sure how to best do it using JTA and JPA and my current architecture.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How many clients do you have? Have often will you want to add a new customer?

Comment: Thats too often, and completely random. I mean, i can add Jboss standalone DS for each client when it comes, or any xml file configuration for each client, and i can create a database for each client in mysql.. but, i dont want to go change my code each time i have a new client.

Comment: The client name can be acquired from logged-in user, from the session..